# How do I get out of initramfs shell and get into gui?

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs, busybox

I'm new to Linux, the only os in my machine is Ubuntu 18.04. When I was using it got all laggy and some apps won't respond so I restarted my machine and instead of it booting straight into Ubuntu grub appeared. And then when I selected Ubuntu in grub, it says `initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed`. then I got to drop into `initramfs` shell. I've tried things like `exit` command from some answers on this forum, but it says `gave up waiting for root filesystem device common problems: Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)`
Check `rootdelay=` (did the system wait long enough) missing modules (`cat /proc/modules; 1s /dev`). Being a neophyte and having to tackle this is very demoralising. I hope Linux experts on this forum will help me out to get to GUI.

**UPDATE:**

I reinstalled ubuntu but all I had to do apparently was do a manual fsck, whatever that is, as my filesystem was broken and grub could not detect it. I just used a live usb to backup my files and reinstalled.

Comment: A fresh re install would be the fastest unless there is a reason you can not do that. Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?